# assigning environment variables in docker

Tags: docker, heroku

I want to provide a custom port for zipkin via $PORT variable, and want it to be assigned to the $QUERY_PORT variable. So, I want to write a Dockerfile such that I should be able to do -

```
docker build -t my-zipkin .
docker run -e PORT=3425 my-zipkin
```

and the zipkin container runs on port 3425. My try -

```
FROM openzipkin/zipkin
ENV QUERY_PORT=$PORT
```

---

*usecase - I want to deploy a zipkin server to heroku. zipkin expects QUERY_PORT variable to be set, while heroku sets the $PORT variable and expects apps to listen for this dynamically provided port.*

Comment: That `Dockerfile` is trying to get the value of `PORT` when you are building it. (I don't know if that is possible)  However, you are trying to pass it in when you are running it.  By that time, the `Dockerfile` has been executed.  I would also like to know how you can modify an image so that the existing default `RUN` command is run with a modified environment that depends on the environment variables passed in.

Comment: yes, providing at build time isnt an option. I want the runtime env var $PORT to set the variable $QUERY_PORT. in heroku, I tried setting the variable $QUERY_PORT and giving it the value $PORT, that too didnt work for me...